# Installing a Certificate in the Keychain Failed - Xcode, Mac OSX

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode8

I've been trying for 72 hours now to fix this error I keep getting from Xcode. So I updated to Xcode 8 and when I try to install an iOS provisioning profile. I keep getting this

> Installing a certificate in the keychain failed (Error Domain=DVTSecErrorDomain Code=100013 "UNIX[Permission denied]" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=UNIX[Permission denied]})

then this..
[image]

I've gone to my files and the permissions look fine and I've searched through the web but can't find a solution to the issue. I don't know a walk around to this. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: does this error appear even before you have the opportunity to click a "create" button in that dialog?  or does it appear only after you click a "create" button?

Comment: after I click the create button @MichaelDautermann

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new admin user on your mac. Log in as that user and try to build.

It is not a very elegant nor definitive solution, but it may help you if you are in a hurry.

Comment: I messed up with my Mac a few months back but factory resetting it solved my problem. Thank you so much for helping